# How to get Azure Resource Group Tag value programmatically

Tags: c#, azure, cloud

I' m trying to get tag of the resource group programmatically.

I can get resource group types with *StorageManagementClient* class.

```
StorageManagementClient storageClient =
            CloudContext.Clients.CreateStorageManagementClient(creds);

var responses = storageClient.StorageAccounts.List();

foreach (var storageService in responses)
{
      foreach(var value in storageService.ExtendedProperties.Values)
      {
           if (value.Equals("Group"))
           {
               //TODO I want to get key and value of tag
           }
      }
}
```

How can I get key and value of tag of the Group?

Comment: You'll need to use the [Azure Resource Manager library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn910477.aspx) to get the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Azure Resource Manager site - https://resources.azure.com

This shows you the Powershell & C# code using HTTP/s requests.

Sometimes the client libraries aren't as up to date as calling the APIs directly.

For straight out tasks, this way is lightweight and relatively simple.

Hope it helps,

Mick.